# PhoneGap app doesnt show images consistently

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, vs-web-application-project, ipod-touch

I have created phonegap app for iPhone and iPod touch, though i use to test it on iPod touch.

**Problem:** The images show up randomly, else it would show a question mark within the placeholder. I have tried running this app at several places like iPhone, iPod, desktop browser (with click event, not touch). Out of which on iPod and Desktop browser it seems to run fine, whereas on iPhone or iPhone Simulator I get random images to be broken.
Its an gallery for images, thus images are most important.

Any suggestions or pointers appreciated.

**Below is a sample page code:**

```
<div  id="galleryRava" >
        <div id="galleryRavaScroll">
            <!--gallery scroll frame-->
            <!-- /header -->
            <div>
                <div id="galleryRavalist">
                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="capsicum_rava_masala"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/capsicum_rava_masala.JPG">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Capsicum Rava Masala</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                        <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="coconut_rava"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/coconut_rava.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Coconut Rava</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="crispy_rava"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/crispy_rava.JPG">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Crispy rava</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="kanchipuram_achari_rava"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/kanchipuram_achari_rava.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Kanchipuram achari rava</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="onion_rava"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/onion_rava.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Onion Rava</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery-item">
                        <a href="#detailPage" >
                        <div class="galleryimage" id="udupi_rava"><img src="images/sankalp/rava/udupi_rava.JPG">
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemJoinBar"></div>
                        <span class="gallerytitle">Udipi rava</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> <br><br><br></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
        </div><!--gallery scroll ends here-->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately clear where you're loading the images from. Are these images stored somewhere, online? Or are you trying to access images that are already stored on the device?

And is it correct to say that sometimes the images show up, and sometimes they do not? Have you had an instance where you've had **all** the images appear? Or is there always at least one image missing?

Comment: yes, the images are stored on the device. yes, i have several image on the screen but randomly images get broken, its not specific image it could be any image at any run cycle. Though i am testing this on iPhone 3GS, on iPod it seems to run fine.

Comment: Odd that it's happening to images that are currently stored on your device. Could you perhaps update your question with the code you're using to locate and display your images?

Comment: Those are just image tags with src property set to some local image url. I am using several divs with several images in each div. It is just that the file is full of divs with images with img tag. I can post those html code though, if u are still curious.

Comment: I'd say post the code in your original question, and others might be able to spot if anything's amiss.

Comment: Sample page posted for convinience.

Comment: I am still at the same stage. I also doubt that it could be memory issue, but how do I track?